# Json file content in chrome extension notifications

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

Can I insert the value from json file in my chrome notifications create method?I want to get the icon and contents from json file

Comment: Why not? If it's in accessible location then just read it with XMLHttpRequest and parse.

Comment: Please share some sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will need to add permission in manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [ "storage", "history", "notifications" ],
```

I am assuming you have json like this:

```
var noti = {
            "iconUrl":"logo.png", 
            "title":"Frst Notification", 
            "message":"This is a chrome extension notification"
          };
```

Use this simple code to create a notification.

```
 chrome.notifications.create('Notifiy-1', {
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: noti.iconUrl,
        title: noti.title,
        message: noti.message
    }, function(notificationId) {});
```